# How do I make my MPMoviePlayerController Play in Landscape?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6

I am trying to make my video from youtube play in landscape mode. I turned off landscape left and right for supported device orientation because if it was on, every view is able to go landscape. I'm building this for iOS 6. How do I make my video play in landscape.

Here is my code

```
#import "VideoTViewController.h"
#import "HCYoutubeParser.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface VideoTViewController ()

@end

@implementation VideoTViewController
@synthesize tLabel;

-(IBAction)playVideo
{

    NSDictionary *videos = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zz_bJ58LfCg&feature=youtu.be"]];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[videos objectForKey:@"medium"]]];

    [self presentViewController:mp animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Edit:**

I did the following:

Made a new class

AboutNavViewController (which subclasses a UiNavigationController)

```
#import "AboutNavViewController.h"

@interface AboutNavViewController ()

@end

@implementation AboutNavViewController


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
@end
```

And in my aboutviewcontroller (which subclasses a uiviewcontroller)

```
#import "AboutViewController.h"
#import "AboutNavViewController.h"

@interface AboutViewController ()

@end

@implementation AboutViewController
@synthesize aLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    aLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [aLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SerifGothic LT Black" size:25]];
    aLabel.text = @"Sephardi Jews";
    aLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    aLabel.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = aLabel;

    AboutNavViewController *about = [[AboutNavViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController:about animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

@end
```

I get the following error:

Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note: You must add landscape left and right to your supported interface orientations in Info.plist for this to work.

> The system determines whether an orientation is supported by intersecting the value returned by the app’s supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: method with the value returned by the supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most full-screen controller.

Added iOS 6 autorotation methods from previous answer"

```
@interface MyMovieViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController
@end

@implementation MyMovieViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

@end
```

Comment: Great it works. Now what if I want a view that is controlled by a navigation controller to work only in portrait mode

Comment: Same thing. Subclass the navigation controller and return portrait only on the autorotation methods. Remember to add portrait mode to supported interface orientations in your Info.plist

Comment: I edited my question to show u what I did, and the error I got. It's really weird what is going on. It shows a black screen instead showing me the uitextview with the about think I created.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to call presentViewController in viewDidLoad method since the view stack might not have completely been created yet. Try putting it in your viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear method and use performSelector:withDelay (couple of seconds should be ok).

Comment: How would I do the performSelector, can you give me an example?

Comment: I did this: -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AboutNavViewController *about = [[AboutNavViewController alloc] init];
    
    [self performSelector:[self presentViewController:about animated:YES completion:nil] withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
    

}